# javascript + phoneGap - how to detect when in an active phone call

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I searched for this question and it's a question that has remained unanswered, I was wondering if anyone could help to figure this out...

Using javascript libraries and phonegap, I would like to place a phone call and when the call is answered play an audio file to the recipient. This audio should only be played to the recipient and not through the phone speakers. In other words, the audio is played as a part of the active call. An example would be when calling a local store and the the call is put on hold while a music is played for the caller.

- Question 1)
  Is there any techniques or plugins that anyone knows which would allow for detecting when a call is actually active/answered?
- Question 2)
  How to play the prerecorded audio .mp3 while in an active call?

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably first take a look at how it is done in native.

Question 1 goes through listening for the system sending the event `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` and it's 'childs'.

A google search for Question 2 suggests something like;

```
    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, mySampleRate, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
    myBuffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Maybe this info can give you a more specific search if phonegap made any translations for this.